# How to insert some R functions to a website to automate data they scrape from another site web and then plot graphs with highcharter

Tags: html, r, highcharts

I want to use some of my R functions in the website i'm creating.
Some of my R functions will scrape data from others website, clean some data and then show the remaining data as table in my website.
Others R functions will plot differents graph using the previous data.
Can this be possible?
Should i convert my R code to html or javascript and insert it in the web?

A minimal r function code example :

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

BRVM_cap <- function(){
  # company<-toupper(company)
  tryCatch({
    brvm_cap <- rvest::read_html("https://www.brvm.org/en/capitalisations/0/status/200") %>%
      rvest::html_nodes('table') %>%
      rvest::html_table()
    brvm_cap <- brvm_cap[[4]]
    brvm_cap$`Global capitalization (%)`<-gsub(",", ".",brvm_cap$`Global capitalization (%)`)
    brvm_cap <- tibble::as.tibble(brvm_cap)
    return(brvm_cap)

  },
  error = function(e) {
    print("Make sure you have an active internet connection")
  },
  warning = function(w) {
    print("Make sure you have an active internet connection")
  })
}
```

How can i insert BRVM_cap function in my website?

Comment: have a look at shiny. https://shiny.rstudio.com/

Comment: thanks but I created a website with rshiny (create the site with only R codes) but what I want now is a bit different; use r code functions in web html (or javascript).